# Tried to run Corb in windows machine

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-corb

I tried running sample corb example by following Corb2 documentation. I  have MarkLogic 10 in my machine and for that I had downloaded the following jars:

- marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar
- marklogic-xcc-10.0.10

And created uris.xqy and transform.xqy files as specified in documentation and kept all these in a corb folder. When I tried running it, it is showing and error like below

```
PS C:\Users\Balaji\Downloads\corb\corb> java -server -cp "marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar;marklogic-xcc-10.0.10" com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager -DOPTIONS-FILE=job.properties
```

> Error: Unable to initialize main class com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/marklogic/xcc/exceptions/XccConfigException

But Java home path has bee set

```
PS C:\Users\Balaji\Downloads\corb\corb> java -version
java version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)
```

Is there any other configuration changes need to be done to run CORB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see that error about not finding the XCC class when the XCC jar is not on the classpath.

You are missing the `.jar` file extension on the XCC jar in your classpath argument.

It should be: `-cp "marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar;marklogic-xcc-10.0.10.jar"`

instead of: `-cp "marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar;marklogic-xcc-10.0.10"`